# Problem with zooming in and out in my game

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a sprite called `gameSprite`, it contains all elements in the game. I have an object called `myCell`, and I am trying to make the cell be always in the middle of the screen, which is 800x600.

This one works:

```
var panX:Number = myCell.x - 800.0 / 2;
var panY:Number = myCell.y - 600.0 / 2;
```

But my problem is that I am trying to allow players to zoom in and out.

Zooming in and out adjusts the `gameSprite.scaleX` and `gameSprite.scaleY` (note they are scaleX is always equal to scaleY).

scaleX is 1.0 for original size, and the lower it is, the more zoomed out the player is.

Then I changed it so it would work with the zoom, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
var panX:Number = myCell.x - 800.0 / 2 / gameSprite.scaleX;
var panY:Number = myCell.y - 600.0 / 2 / gameSprite.scaleY;
```

I have no idea about what I did wrong.

Here's a screenshot without any zoom:
[image]

And the more I zoom, the more the camera moves away from the 0, 0 position:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to be able to scale your object from it's center point.
Take a look at the following link:

http://ryanbosinger.com/blog/2008/actionscript-30-scale-object-from-center-point/

Comment: Thank you! I had forgotten how to name my problem.